# Removing repeating data in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to remove repeatitive values I get from a table

Say for example I have this data below:

```
Data Table
------------------------------------------------
ID    | StudentName   |   Subject   |   Club   |
------------------------------------------------
1     |  Bryan        |  Math       | Astronomy|
1     |  Bryan        |  Science    | Astronomy|
1     |  Bryan        |  English    | Chess    |
2     | Smith         |  Math       | Soccer   |
2     | Smith         |  English    | Soccer   |
2     | Smith         |  Math       | FootBall |
------------------------------------------------
```

I wanted the result of something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ID    | StudentName     |  Subjects              |        Clubs      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | Bryan           | Math, Science, English | Astronomy | Chess |
2     | Smith           | Math, English          | Soccer | Football |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Given the data from above I'm aware that you could just seperate the clubs from the subjects and then go from there as a good practice. But I wanted to do it in a single query if its even possible at all.

What I've tried:

```
Select DISTINCT ID, 
       StudentName, 
       string_agg(Subject, ',') as Subjects, 
       string_agg(Club, ',') as Clubs 
FROM Data
Group By ID, StudentName
```

However the results have multiple values like: `Subject, Math, Math for Smith`.

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Postgres or a related database, then you can just use `distinct`:

```
select ID, StudentName,
       string_agg(distinct Subject, ',') as Subjects,
       string_agg(distinct Club, ',') as Clubs 
from Data 
group by ID, StudentName;
```

SQL Server does not support `distinct` with `string_agg()`.  In that database, you can use a subquery:

```
select ID, StudentName,
       string_agg(case when seqnum_s = 1 then Subject end, ',') as Subjects,
       string_agg(case when seqnum_c = 1 then Club end, ',') as Clubs 
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, studentname, subject order by subject) as seqnum_s,
             row_number() over (partition by id, studentname, subject order by club) as seqnum_c
      from Data d
     ) d
group by ID, StudentName;
```